# Pass a parent activity object into AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to pass the parent activity which called the Asynctask  into Asynctask..

Below is a part of my code i want to use an activity object in doinbackground parameters instead of string but i cant because i ab unable to do it.. please explain how to do it..

```
public class Backgroundtask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {  
      AlertDialog alertDialog;  
      AlertDialog alertDialog2;  
       Context ctx;  
       Userlocalstore userlocalstore;
       String res_name , res_username , res_dob , res_email , res_id , res_pass;
       Backgroundtask(Context ctx)  
       {  
        this.ctx =ctx;  
       }  

       @Override  
       protected void onPreExecute() {  
       alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();  
         alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");  
         alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();  

         alertDialog2.setTitle("Apologies");  
       }  

       @Override  
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  
         String reg_url = "http://8miles.freeiz.com/Register.php";  
         String login_url = "http://8miles.freeiz.com/getuserinfo.php";  
         String method = params[0];  
         if (method.equals("Register")) {  
           String name = params[1];  
           String user_name = params[2];  
           String user_pass = params[3];  
           String email = params[4];  
           String dob = params[5];
```

Comment: Passing an Activity into an AsyncTask can be a bit dangerous-  if the AsyncTask never ends, then the Activity will be leaked.  And either way it will continue to take up memory even after the Activity is finished until the task does end.  THis includes in rotation cases.  Be careful here.

Comment: You should probably not do that for the reasons mentioned by Gabe Sechan, but you can simply replace your `Context ctx` with an Activity, since an Activity is also a Context.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Backgroundtask` an inner class inside an `Activity`? If so, you wont need to pass a `Context` parameter. Instead, you can use `*ActivityName*.this`.

That aside, your method looks fine. You may want to make your constructor `public`.

Comment: Implicit references are hard references, so that would be a potential leak.

Answer (score 0):

From the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html site:  "Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.". So when you extend the AsyncTask class with your Backgroundtask, you can say:

```
public class Backgroundtask extends AsyncTask<GenericTypeOfYourChoice, Void, String>
```

and pass your object as a first parameter of the .execute() method, e.g.:

```
new Backgroundtask().execute(instanceOfGenericTypeOfYourChoice);
```